# How to rearrange values with columns in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I have the below data

```
site | ID

abc  | 1

abc  | 2

abc  | 3
.
.
.
abc  | n
```

I need the below output.

```
  site | ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |...| ID_n

  abc  |   1  |   2  |   3  |...|  n
```

I tried using `group by`, `Normalizer` steps. But not able to handle n number of values to create n number of columns.

Comment: Number of columns are fixed or varies for different datasets?

Comment: It will vary. Hence I have generalised the question